# How can I display an image inside two tags using Javascript

Tags: javascript

This is what I've tried, but it's not working.

```
getImg = document.getElementById('mainId').getElementsByTagName('a').getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve by above code?

Answer (score 0):

If you look in your web console, you'll see it complaining about this:

```
getImg = document.getElementById('mainId').getElementsByTagName('a').getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
// Error -----------------------------------------------------------^
```

`getElementsByTagName` returns a `NodeList`, not an element, and so it doesn't have a `getElementsByTagName` method.

Assuming the structure is as you expect, you can use the *first* `a` like this:

```
getImg = document.getElementById('mainId').getElementsByTagName('a')[0].getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
// Change is here --------------------------------------------------^^^
```

If you want to deal with all of the images inside the links, you'll need a loop.